# Add specific characters to duplicated strings

Tags: r

I have a vector of names:

```
> dput(vec_dup)
c("Mark", "Simon", "Marcus", "Greg", "Simon", "Greg", "Marta", 
"Marta", "Tim", "Tim", "Greg", "Tom", "Tom", "Greg")
```

Some of the names are repeated within this vector. I would like to add to each of the string specific characters `_1`, `_2`, `_3`. Added number depends when it appears in a vector and how many times appeared earlier.

Desired output:

```
vec_output <- c("Mark_1", "Simon_1", "Marcus_1", "Greg_1", "Simon_2", "Greg_2", "Marta_1", 
                "Marta_2", "Tim_1", "Tim_2", "Greg_3", "Tom_1", "Tom_2", "Greg_4")
```

AS you see it is not only about duplicated strings because `Marcus` appeared only once in a string and still should get `_1`. How to do it effectively for couple of thousands strings ?

Comment: `make.unique(vec_dup)`

Comment: That looks very effective however the output is not the same as my desired.

Comment: How so? It adds suffix to duplicates. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: This function adds suffix to duplicates but I would like to add suffix also to non-duplicated strings. The title was not completely correct.

Comment: I do not see the point why but nevertheless, I reopened and added an answer.

Comment: To be honest there is no a good reason for doing that way except all of the scripts I have previously generated work on this kind of data. Thx.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on your requirement, you can use `ave` to group by the same words and paste a suffix based on the sequence of each group, i.e.

```
ave(vec_dup, vec_dup, FUN = function(i) paste0(i, '_', seq_along(i)))
#[1] "Mark_1"   "Simon_1"  "Marcus_1" "Greg_1"   "Simon_2"  "Greg_2"   "Marta_1"  "Marta_2"  "Tim_1"    "Tim_2"    "Greg_3"   "Tom_1"    "Tom_2"   
#[14] "Greg_4"
```

If you don't care about adding suffix to all but just differentiating between the dupes , then simply `make.unique` would suffice, i.e.

```
make.unique(vec_dup, sep = '_')
#[1] "Mark"    "Simon"   "Marcus"  "Greg"    "Simon_1" "Greg_1"  "Marta"   "Marta_1" "Tim"     "Tim_1"   "Greg_2"  "Tom"     "Tom_1"   "Greg_3"
```

Answer (score 1):

Combined approach: Allowing unique values without index as with `make.unique` and beginning with _1 for duplicates as in other approaches

```
string<-c("Mark", "Simon", "Marcus", "Greg", "Simon", "Greg", "Marta", 
  "Marta", "Tim", "Tim", "Greg", "Tom", "Tom", "Greg")
mstring <- make.unique(as.character(string), sep="_" )
tmp <- !duplicated(string)
for (i in 1:length(mstring[tmp])){
    mstring[tmp][i]<-ifelse(string[tmp][i] %in% string[duplicated(string)]
                            , gsub("(.*)","\\1_0", mstring[tmp][i])
                            , mstring[tmp][i]
    )
}
end <- sub(".*_([0-9]+)","\\1",grep("_([0-9]*)$",mstring,value=T) )
beg <- sub("(.*_)[0-9]+","\\1",grep("_([0-9]*)$",mstring,value=T) )
newend <- as.numeric(end)+1
mstring[grep("_([0-9]*)$",mstring)] <- paste0(beg,newend)
mstring 
# "Mark"    "Simon_1" "Marcus"  "Greg_1"  "Simon_2" "Greg_2"  "Marta_1" "Marta_2" 
# "Tim_1"   "Tim_2"   "Greg_3"  "Tom_1"   "Tom_2"   "Greg_4"
```

As a function:

```
make.unique.1 <- function(string,sep="_") {
  mstring <- make.unique(as.character(string), sep=sep )
  if(sep=="."){ sep <- "\\."}
  tmp <- !duplicated(string)
  for (i in seq_along(mstring[tmp])){
    mstring[tmp][i] <- ifelse(string[tmp][i] %in% string[duplicated(string)]
                              , gsub("(.*)",paste0("\\1",sep,"0"), mstring[tmp][i])
                              , mstring[tmp][i]
    )
  }
  end <- sub(paste0(".*" ,sep,"([0-9]+)"),"\\1",grep(paste0(sep,"([0-9]*)$")
          ,mstring,value=T) )
  beg <- sub(paste0("(.*",sep,")[0-9]+") ,"\\1",grep(paste0(sep,"([0-9]*)$")
          ,mstring,value=T) )
  newend <- as.numeric(end)+1
  mstring[grep(paste0(sep,"([0-9]*)$"),mstring)] <- paste0(beg,newend)
  mstring
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table::rowid()`:

```
library(data.table)
paste(vec_dup, rowid(vec_dup), sep = "_")
#  [1] "Mark_1"   "Simon_1"  "Marcus_1" "Greg_1"   "Simon_2"  "Greg_2"  
#  [7] "Marta_1"  "Marta_2"  "Tim_1"    "Tim_2"    "Greg_3"   "Tom_1"   
# [13] "Tom_2"    "Greg_4"
```

Answer (score 0):

I used `table` to get the occurrences of each name, store them in a `data.frame` and then `match` the desired column with the original vector:

```
nam <- c("Mark", "Simon", "Marcus", "Greg", "Simon", "Greg", "Marta", 
        "Marta", "Tim", "Tim", "Greg", "Tom", "Tom", "Greg")
occ <- data.frame("name" = names(table(nam)),
                  "occ" = as.numeric(table(nam)))

occ$res <- paste(occ$name, occ$occ, sep = "_")

res <- occ[match(nam, occ$name), "res"]
```

Comment: Check the output from your code. It does not work properly.