# "Marking" Duplicates in R

Tags: r, duplicates, data-manipulation

I am working with the R programming language. Suppose I have the following data:

```
 Data_I_Have <- data.frame(
        
        "Person" = c("John", "John", "John", "Peter", "Peter", "Peter", "Tim", "Kevin", "Adam", "Adam", "Xavier"),
        "Number_of_Kids" = c("4", "1", "1", "5", "2", "3", "7", "0", "3", "3", "5")
     
    )

  Person Number_of_Kids
1    John              4
2    John              1
3    John              1
4   Peter              5
5   Peter              2
6   Peter              3
7     Tim              7
8   Kevin              0
9    Adam              3
10   Adam              3
11 Xavier              5
```

Is it possible to "mark" each duplicate name so that it looks like the file below (e.g. John_1, John_2, etc.)?

```
Data_I_Want <- data.frame(
    
    "Person" = c("John_1", "John_2", "John_3", "Peter_1", "Peter_2", "Peter_3", "Tim", "Kevin", "Adam_1", "Adam_2", "Xavier"),
   "Number_of_Kids" = c("4", "1", "1", "5", "2", "3", "7", "0", "3", "3", "5")
 
)

   Person Number_of_Kids
1   John_1              4
2   John_2              1
3   John_3              1
4  Peter_1              5
5  Peter_2              2
6  Peter_3              3
7      Tim              7
8    Kevin              0
9   Adam_1              3
10  Adam_2              3
11  Xavier              5
```

Using this previous question [Add specific characters to duplicated strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48825010/add-specific-characters-to-duplicated-strings), I tried to follow the method used there:

```
Data_I_Want <-  make.unique(Data_I_Have, sep = '_')
```

But this gives me the following error:

```
Error in make.unique(Data_I_Have, sep = "_") : 
  'names' must be a character vector
```

Can someone please show me how to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`make.unique` expects a vector and not a data.frame and the output by default will append 1, 2, 3 with `.` (as `sep` only from the duplicate values and not from the start. i.e.

```
> make.unique(Data_I_Have$Person)
 [1] "John"    "John.1"  "John.2"  "Peter"   "Peter.1" "Peter.2" "Tim"     "Kevin"   "Adam"    "Adam.1"  "Xavier"
```

If we want to get the desired output, group by 'Person', and concatenate the `row_number()` with the group column and then `ungroup()` it.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
Data_I_Have %>%
    group_by(Person) %>% 
    mutate(Person = case_when(n() > 1 ~
        str_c(Person, "_", row_number()), TRUE ~ Person)) %>% 
    ungroup()
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 11 x 2
   Person  Number_of_Kids
   <chr>   <chr>         
 1 John_1  4             
 2 John_2  1             
 3 John_3  1             
 4 Peter_1 5             
 5 Peter_2 2             
 6 Peter_3 3             
 7 Tim     7             
 8 Kevin   0             
 9 Adam_1  3             
10 Adam_2  3             
11 Xavier  5
```

Comment: @ akrun: thank you so much for your answer! i tried your code and got the following error:

Comment: Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `Person`.
i `Person = case_when(...)`.
x could not find function "str_c"
i The error occurred in group 1: Person = "Adam".

Comment: do you know what might be causing this error? thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @Noob sorry, updated the post.  it is from `library(stringr)`

Comment: @ akrun: thank you so much for your help! after 8 minutes, I will be able to accept your answer!

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative way (update, corrected version):

```
library(dplyr)
Data_I_Have %>% 
    group_by(Person) %>% 
    mutate(id = row_number(),
           n = n(),
           Person = ifelse(n >1, paste(Person, id, sep="_"), Person)) %>% 
    select(-id, -n)
```

```
   Person  Number_of_Kids
   <chr>   <chr>         
 1 John_1  4             
 2 John_2  1             
 3 John_3  1             
 4 Peter_1 5             
 5 Peter_2 2             
 6 Peter_3 3             
 7 Tim     7             
 8 Kevin   0             
 9 Adam_1  3             
10 Adam_2  3             
11 Xavier  5
```

Answer (score 1):

A tidyverse option using `cumsum()`.

```
library(dplyr)

Data_I_Have %>%
  group_by(Person) %>%
  mutate(cnt = 1,
         Person = str_c(Person, cumsum(cnt), sep = '_')) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-cnt)

# # A tibble: 11 x 2
#   Person    Number_of_Kids
#   <chr>     <chr>         
# 1 John_1    4             
# 2 John_2    1             
# 3 John_3    1             
# 4 Peter_1   5             
# 5 Peter_2   2             
# 6 Peter_3   3             
# 7 Tim_1     7             
# 8 Kevin_1   0             
# 9 Adam_1    3             
# 10 Adam_2   3             
# 11 Xavier_1 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Using data.table, where `.N` is a symbol for the number of rows in the group.

```r
Data_I_Have <- data.frame(
  "Person" = c("John", "John", "John", "Peter", "Peter", "Peter", "Tim", "Kevin", "Adam", "Adam", "Xavier"),
  "Number_of_Kids" = c("4", "1", "1", "5", "2", "3", "7", "0", "3", "3", "5")
)

library(data.table)
setDT(Data_I_Have)

Data_I_Have[, Person := if (.N == 1) Person else paste0(Person, "_", seq(.N)),
            by = Person]

Data_I_Have
#>      Person Number_of_Kids
#>  1:  John_1              4
#>  2:  John_2              1
#>  3:  John_3              1
#>  4: Peter_1              5
#>  5: Peter_2              2
#>  6: Peter_3              3
#>  7:     Tim              7
#>  8:   Kevin              0
#>  9:  Adam_1              3
#> 10:  Adam_2              3
#> 11:  Xavier              5
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>